# Magento: pass custom value per product in order

Tags: php, magento, parameter-passing, cart

I have created custom field (dropdown field) in Magento cart page. User will able to choose any option from this field. I have created this field manually means I didn't use Magento product custom option. My requirement is that now I want to pass the field value whatever the customer wants per product in order.

thanks

Comment: create product attribute http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/configurable-product-step-1-create-dropdown-attributes/

Comment: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html

Comment: But I don't want to create any product attribute and product custom option. I just want to know how can I pass custom parameter value per product in magento order?